# How can I center a button in TailwindCSS?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I cannot figure out how to center a button.

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import Image from "next/Image";


const Login = ({ providers }) => {
  
  
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
      <div className="container max-w-l mx-auto">
        <img src="/logo.png" alt="image description"></img>
      </div>
      
      <div className="flex-auto justify-center items-center h-screen">
        {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
          <div key={provider.name}>
            <button
              className="bg-[#18D860] text-white p-5 rounded-lg flex-auto px-12 py-2 text-lg tracking-widest uppercase rounded-full focus:outline-none bg-primary hover:bg-opacity-80"
              onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackUrl: "/posts/dashboard" })}
            >
              Login with {provider.name}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

No matter what I do, it either shoots to the top of the screen or to the bottom left. I have tried flex boxes, containers, auto scaling, everything. I tried to use things like "justify-center, align-center, grid, flex", nothing worked--the most consistent result was to shoot the login button to the top right or lower left of the screen.

Comment: Can you show how it should look? Because you are putting a image that has auto margins without dimensions next to the button in a flex container. That will never center anything. Could you clarify with a example of how this should actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

By `Center` if you mean vertically center then you may have to change

```
<div className="flex-auto justify-center items-center h-screen">
```

to

```
<div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
```

This will get your button next to the image.

Answer (score -1):

try to add the  tag to your code

```html
 <div className="flex-auto justify-center items-center h-screen">
        {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
          <div key={provider.name}>
 --->         <center>
            <button
              className="bg-[#18D860] text-white p-5 rounded-lg flex-auto px-12 py-2 text-lg tracking-widest uppercase rounded-full focus:outline-none bg-primary hover:bg-opacity-80"
              onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackUrl: "/posts/dashboard" })}
            >
              Login with {provider.name}
              </button>
            </center>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

you can add this tag any other place
good luck!!

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your time! This did not work.

Comment: The `<center>` tag is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Consider removing or modifying your answer.